# Density of states in deferent dimension

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, density-of-states

Why the density of states in 2D is constant?

Or in 3D why DOS is related to E^1/2 and in 1D and 0D how we can explain the relations physically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour that you have mentioned seems most likely to be true when you are looking at situations where you can ignore the potential energy term and hence you are essentially dealing with free particle. For instance, consider the Hamiltonian for a single particle in $D$ dimensions

$ H(q,p) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} p_{i}^{2} + V(\{q_{i}\})$

where we have just set constants to one. Now the density of states at energy $E$ is given as

$ \rho(E) = \int \prod_{i} dq_{i}\, dp_{i}\, \delta(H(q,p)-E)$

This is basically counting the volume of phase space where you have energy E. Now, if the physical constraints of the problem allow us to set $V(q)\approx 0$, then

$ \rho(E) = (Vol) \int \prod_{i} dp_{i}\, \delta(\sum p^{2}_{i} - E)$

The integral can be solved by going to spherical coordinates and so $(\sum p^{2}_{i} = r^{2})$ and $\prod_{i} dp_{i} \propto r^{D-1}dr$. Using this, we have

$\int \prod_{i} dp_{i}\, \delta(\sum p^{2}_{i} - E) \propto \int dr \, r^{D-1}\delta(r^{2}-E) = \int dy \, \frac{y^{\frac{D}{2}-1}}{2}\delta(y-E) $

Which finally gives us that $\rho(E) \propto E^{\frac{D}{2}-1}$. One can easily get the relations you mentioned by substituting $D=1,2,3,\dots$ in the expression.

Comment: @Artem Alexandro  your explanation is simple and good. Now I want to know how we can interpret this results in 1, 2 and 3D? For example in 3D can we say the avaiable states for particles goes to zero when energy decreases? If yes what does mean physically? Or I can't understand  in 2D why the density is constant?

Answer (score 0):

What is density of states in general case? It is the ratio of the number of states $\Delta g$, which are lie in the energy interval $\Delta E$,
$$g(E)=\frac{\Delta g}{\Delta E}.$$
Consider now the case of infinitesimal quantities and RHS of this expression becomes the derivative,
$$g(E)=\frac{d g}{d E}.$$
To be more concrete, let us consider 3D case with a quantum particle in infinite square well with width $L$. The particle wave-vector is the discrete quantity,
$$k_i=\frac{\pi n}{L}, n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Now consider case of large $L$, so $k$ seems continuous. What is the number of states in this case? All the states lie in the sphere with radius $k$. It is straightforward to understand that different states correspond to 1/8 of this sphere. In real space, for the single value of $k$ we have the volume $(\pi/ L)^3$. So,
$$g(k)=\frac{1}{8}\frac{4}{3}\pi k^3\frac{1}{(\pi L)^3}$$
Taking into account that $E(k)=k^2/(2m)$ and using the relation
$$g(E)=\frac{\partial g(k)}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial E},$$
you can easily obtain that $g(E)\sim E^{1/2}$. Then, in similar way you should consider case of 2D & 1D. There are two key poitns. First, in 2D instead of sphere you will consider a circle (in 1D you'll consider a segment). Second, the dispersion law is important: in case of free particles you have $E(k)=k^2/(2m)$ but the sitatuation can be more complicated (hopefully, enough weak interaction just renormalizes particle mass, roughly speaking).

*Physically*, you should understand how to calculate the volume in momentum space of a system with fixed energy $E$, know which volume in real space has one state and then just calculate the density.